# Deploying a Qt 5.5.1 C++ application on multiple Linux distributions

Tags: c++, linux, qt, deployment

I have an application written in pure C++ and Qt 5.5.1. It compiles fine in both GCC (Lubuntu 15.10 x86) and MSVC 14.0 (Windows 8.1 x64), and works properly on both those platforms. I now want to distribute it so that it will run on other Linux distros without recompiling them there.

I'm not entirely sure how to achieve this; the [Qt docs page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html) generally suggests to link everything statically, but this is not what most other sources say (from what I understand it is a bad idea to link with `glibc` statically). In any case I cannot really link *everything* statically because GCC complains that `Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking` and from what I understand this isn't a warning one can simply ignore. I've tired linking statically against only `libgcc` and `libstdc++`, I copied the other missing libraries - `libXau.so.6`, `libXdmcp.so.6` and `libxcb.so.1` on a clean CentOS 7 installation and tried to run the program there, but that gave me a segmentation fault; possibly because the system is 64 bit as opposed to the platform I compiled the application on?

- How can I distribute the application in a form runnable by most common configurations? Static linking is not an issue because the source is going to be released anyway.
- Is it better to link against Qt statically or dynamically (if maximum binary portability is the priority)?
- Do I need to provide two separate versions of the binary, 32 and 64 bit, or will a 32 bit build suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to offer two builds: an unsupported, fully static build that will work "anywhere" with an asterisk that there's no way you can support it if it's a commercial offering. People'll try to run it on their fridges, I kid you not. The officially supported builds must be for **specific** platforms only, and you can't but have VMs/test targets that run these platforms, and where you build and test on.

Comment: `an unsupported, fully static build` - do you mean I should ignore the warning that matching shared libraries are required to be present on the target machine?

Comment: @szczurcio - you don't need any libs with static linking

Comment: The interface between your fully static build and the target is at the syscall and socket interface level (e.g. for X11 calls). As long as a sensible kernel version, device node layout and X server version is present, your code will "run".

Comment: @ddriver Please read the question carefully - when linking statically (i.e. passing the `-static` flag to `ld`), you still get a warning that certain shared libraries will be used. See here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725255/create-statically-linked-binary-that-uses-getaddrinfo