# Static linked vips (libvips) binary

Tags: static-libraries, vips

I have been attempting to create a statically linked version of vips but have been unable to. Is it possible to create a statically linked vips command?

The platform I am compiling on is Ubuntu 16.04.

The make command I am running:

```
 make LDFLAGS=-all-static
```

I am not configuring it to use python or imagemagick, (those show "no" in the config output). The error I am getting is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.a(libgio_2_0_la-glocalfileinfo.o): In function `lookup_gid_name':
(.text+0x11d7): warning: Using 'getgrgid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.a(libgio_2_0_la-glocalvfs.o): In function `g_local_vfs_parse_name':
(.text+0x1cd): warning: Using 'getpwnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o): In function `g_get_user_database_entry':
(.text+0x249): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o): In function `g_get_user_database_entry':
(.text+0xcf): warning: Using 'getpwnam_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.a(libgio_2_0_la-glocalfileinfo.o): In function `lookup_uid_data':
(.text+0x1054): warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.a(nanohttp.o): In function `xmlNanoHTTPConnectHost':
(.text+0x924): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.a(nanohttp.o): In function `xmlNanoHTTPConnectHost':
(.text+0x9f4): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.a(libgio_2_0_la-gnetworkaddress.o): In function `g_network_address_parse':
(.text+0xc39): warning: Using 'getservbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.a(libgio_2_0_la-gnetworkaddress.o): In function `g_network_address_parse':
(.text+0xc4e): warning: Using 'endservent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:597: recipe for target 'vips' failed
make[2]: *** [vips] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/vips-8.4.1/tools'
Makefile:631: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/vips-8.4.1'
Makefile:536: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

From what I've found on, for example here:
[Create statically-linked binary that uses getaddrinfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725255/create-statically-linked-binary-that-uses-getaddrinfo)
is that this is an issue with libnss. But in the ./configure --help output there is no --enable-static-flag. Even so I tried that and it didn't fix my problem.

The libraries I am linking against (according to the config output, I've truncated it):

```
build radiance support:         yes
build analyze support:          yes
build PPM support:          yes
use fftw3 for FFT:          yes
accelerate loops with orc:      yes
ICC profile support with lcms:      yes (lcms2)
SVG import with librsvg-2.0:        yes
zlib:                   yes
file import/export with libwebp:    yes
file import/export with libpng:     yes (pkg-config libpng >= 1.2.9)
file import/export with libtiff:    yes (pkg-config libtiff-4)
file import/export with giflib:     yes (found by search)
file import/export with libjpeg:    yes
use libexif to load/save JPEG metadata: yes
```

Is there a particular library I am linking against that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

After failing to convince the build mechanism to statically link, I was able to successfully create a working static `vips` executable with `staticx`, after reporting [an issue](https://github.com/JonathonReinhart/staticx/issues/132#issuecomment-647871832) to staticx and seeing that it was fixed. See [here](https://github.com/joshuarli/static-builders/blob/master/vips-glibc-gcc/Dockerfile) for how I'm building.

Just in case that link of mines dies in the future, here are the relevant parts:

```
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/libvips/libvips/releases/download/v8.9.2/vips-8.9.2.tar.gz | tar -xz -f- --strip-components=1 -C .

# TODO: Add --disable-deprecated
# Blocked by https://github.com/libvips/libvips/pull/1593

# XXX: -static doesn't work here, I'm using staticx to make the final vips binary static.
RUN CFLAGS="-O3 -flto -pipe" CXXFLAGS="-O3 -flto -pipe" \
    ./configure \
        --disable-shared \
        --disable-static \
        --disable-dependency-tracking

# This is the fastest easiest way I found to compile the
# CLI as fast as possible. You can probably get more optimal,
# but it'd be a lot harder wrestling autotools.
RUN cd libvips \
    && make -j"$(nproc)"
RUN cd tools \
    && make -j"$(nproc)" vips

RUN cd tools \
    && staticx vips ../vips
```

Since configure automatically feature-detects, here are the Debian 10 (June 22) packages I installed:

```
    libglib2.0-dev \
    libexpat1-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libimagequant-dev \
    libexif-dev \
    liborc-0.4-dev
```

It weighs 3.3M, which is fairly impressive and a heck of a lot smaller than distribution packages, which is why I set out to do this in the first place.

```
$ file vips-glibc-gcc
vips-glibc-gcc: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
$ ls -lah vips-glibc-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 josh josh 3.3M Jun 23 02:51 vips-glibc-gcc
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried like this:

```
$ CFLAGS="-static" CXXFLAGS="-static" ./configure --prefix=/home/john/vips --without-python --without-magick
```

And it seems to work:

```
$ ls ~/vips/lib
girepository-1.0  libvipsCC.a   libvips-cpp.a   libvips.la  python2.7
libvips.a         libvipsCC.la  libvips-cpp.la  pkgconfig
$ which vips
/home/john/vips/bin/vips
$ ls -l ~/vips/bin/vips
-rwxr-xr-x 1 john john 6373864 Sep 27 13:16 /home/john/vips/bin/vips
$ vips invert /data/john/pics/k2.jpg x.jpg
$ eog x.jpg
```

I've not tested it much though, and I suspect it's not very static. If you run ldd on the `vips` binary, for example, you get a long list. True static binaries do not really exist any more.

Why do you want a static binary? If it's to ease distribution, things like flatpack and snappy might be better. You can also sort-of make your own --- for example, vips comes with a simple wrapper script which can make the shared binary relocatable.

Comment: I was hoping to deploy it in a minimalist docker container that also has static versions of ffmpeg and ffprobe. I guess I just wasn't sure why an image conversion program needs calls like getservbyname so was hoping there was some dependency I could drop.

Comment: vips uses glib to help portability, and glib has a lot of stuff in. You could try making your own glib with some things removed, it might help. I think the static binary ^^^^ would work in any 16.04 install, which is something, but it probably wouldn't work on a very minimal linux install. OpenWRT have a libvips package and that's very minimal, maybe you could adapt that?

Comment: I think using something like dietlibc might work but haven't had a chance to re-visit that yet.