# How to switch from shared library to static library with CMake

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, static-libraries, gdal

### Context:

I built an `a.out` on my local system with a modern CMake project adding a dependency to a shared library:

```
find_package(GDAL QUIET)

if(GDAL_FOUND)
  get_property(_loc TARGET GDAL::GDAL PROPERTY LOCATION)
  message(STATUS "Found GDAL: ${_loc} (version ${GDAL_VERSION})")
  add_library(gdal_external INTERFACE)  # dummy
```

Everything works fine on my system. Now I want to distribute the `a.out` to systems that don't have the dependency (the `.so`).

### Problem:

I copied the binary `a.out` on a cluster, and when I execute it, I get the following error:  `error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.26: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

### Possible solution and other considerations

- Installing the dependencies on the cluster, but I don't have admin rights on this server
- even if I had the dependency installed by the staff, the same problem will arise later when I will ship the binary to possible users
- I can't ask future users to manage dependencies and build from sources.
- It seems to me that I should embed all the dependencies in the same executable, that is using a static library rather than share
- Executable size or memory issues are not the priority

**How do I indicate CMake to use the static version of a library ?**

Comment: So, do you have **static** GDAL library? Obtaining it should obviously be the first step for linking GDAL statically..

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I don't have the static library *yet*, just because I don't want to mess up with my system again. I know I can follow [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511533/building-gdal-with-all-libraries-static) to get it done, but I don't want to engage this path without knowing where it leads and how much time it will cost me :)

Comment: If you build and install GDAL statically into some custom installation prefix, then could ask CMake to search that prefix with `find_package(GDAL)`. So CMake will find static libraries. Is it what you ask?

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes this is what I ask. Once I get the static library, how do I ask CMake to find the static version.

Comment: In the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGDAL.html) you may find `GDAL_DIR` and `GDAL_ROOT` variables, using which you could hint CMake about CGAL location. Variable [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) works for this purpose too. (The variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` affects on internal functionality of `find_package`, so it is not noted in the documentation for specific "FindXXX" modules.)

Comment: If I understand well, CMake will build whatever it finds at the location ? If the dependency code is embedded into the executable depends only on if what CMake finds is a share library or a static library? I would have thought one would required to add a `STATIC` keyword somewhere in the CMake project.